# Meromorphic function with finite isolated singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function and let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be all zeroes of $f$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that there exist real numbers $r_0>0$ and $t>1$ such that $|f(z)|\geq |z|^t$ for all $|z|\geq r_0$. Prove that

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{f},a_j\right)=0$$

I'm fairly sure that you would use Cauchy's integral formula for the computation of the sum of the residues, but I'm not sure how to go about doing so?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Integrate over a circle $\gamma_R$ with radius $R$ around 0. Consider the case $R \to \infty$. Show that $\int _{\gamma_R} \frac{1}{f(z)} dz \to 0$ using the standard inequality for integrals and $\left\vert \frac{1}{f(z)} \right\vert \leq R^{-t}$ for $\vert z \vert =R$ and $R > r_0$. Then use the Cauchy integral formula to represent the same intregral via the residua.

Answer (score 0):

First note that for all $i$, $|a_i| < r_0$, or else if such a $a_j$ is, then $0=|f(a_j)|\geq |a_j|^t$, which implies that $|a_j|=0$ (!). In other words, for all $i$, $a_i \in D(0,r_0)$. Now for any $\epsilon >0$, we integrate over $1/f$ over $\partial D(0,r_0+\epsilon)$. Then by Cauchy's residue theorem, we have $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D(0,r_0+\epsilon)} \frac{dz}{f}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \text{Res}(1/f,a_i)$$ However a simple estimation tells us that $$\bigl \lvert \int_{\partial D(0,r_0+\epsilon)} \frac{dz}{f} \bigr \rvert\leq {2\pi(r_0+\epsilon)}.\text{sup}_{\partial D(0,r_0+\epsilon)}|1/f|\leq \frac{2\pi}{(r_0+\epsilon)^{t-1}}$$ Since $t>1$ and $f$ is entire, we can let $\epsilon \rightarrow \infty$, the RHS of the above approximation will result to $0$. Therefore, $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \text{Res}(1/f,a_i)=0$$

**EDIT:** didn't know that someone already posted a hint! But I will just leave this up in case you need to check on the details :)